# Parsing command line with options and parameters in any order

Tags: c, linux, glibc, command-line-arguments

I'm having trouble thinking of an approach to read in an input file from a command line argument while the arguments can be ordered in different ways.

For example:

```
./a.out -d mazeData1.txt   would read the input file from argv[2]
```

but the command line arguments could also be ordered:

```
./a.out mazeData1.txt -d
```

^ where now the input file is in argv[1]

How could approach finding an input file like this?

Comment: You need to use getopt() to manage the options (i.e. the parameters beginning with "-") and then you will be able to get the last non option parameter.

Comment: You might update your title to match your actual problem. Reading a file is not related to your problem. It's all about parsing command line parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple first approach to getopt(). Please refer to the manual (man 3 getopt) for more information :

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int ac, char *av[])
{
  int opt;
  extern int optind;

  while ((opt = getopt(ac, av, "d")) != -1) {

    switch(opt) {

      case 'd': {

        printf("-%c option\n", opt);   

      }
      break;

      default: {

        printf("Unknown option\n");
        return 1;
      }

    }

  }

  if (av[optind]) {
    printf("First non option parameter: %s\n", av[optind]);
  }

  return 0;

}
```

Comment: POSIX conforming `getopt()` stops at the first non-option argument, so it won't see the `-d` in OP's second example. (The GNU version on the other hand will see it unless the `POSIXLY_CORRECT` environment variable is set).